# Will Linux still receive AF_PACKET if it's not bound to an interface?

Tags: linux, go, linux-kernel

I'm trying to receive a particular type of packet irrespective of the interface it arrives on.

```golang
fd, err := syscall.Socket(syscall.AF_PACKET, syscall.SOCK_RAW, int(htons(0x88cc)))
for {
  len, sa, err := syscall.Recvfrom(fd, buf, 0)
  <process packet>
}
```

Whilst this works, it *only* works when something else binds to an interface it seems. I.e if the application is running *and* I start a tcpdump filtered to the desired data only then will my application receive the desired traffic.

Is this due to interfaces filtering on undirected traffic? How can AF_PACKET listen for a particular ether type on all interfaces on a System?

Comment: What is 0x88cc?

Comment: @rustyx it's `ETH_P_LLDP`, Link Layer Discovery Protocol.

Comment: Yeah apologies, `ETH_P_LLDP` doesn't exist in the go syscall lib